# Function that works as a try except lambda function in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to clean the column of a dataframe so only the first name is left.

What I'm currently trying is splitting each value of the column into a list, and then gathering the [0] of the list, if the element contains a comma, then get the [1].

I try the code below and it works perfectly, **except** for some outlier values that only have the last name with a comma, but no first name as shown in the examples below:

What I used:

```
msgDFt['From Name'] = msgDFt['From Name'].str.split(' ')
msgDFt['From Name'] = msgDFt['From Name'].apply(lambda row: row[0] if ',' not in row[0] else row[1])
```

Now I'm aware that lambda functions do not have the feature of having a try-except, the next thing  I tried was a function:

```
def firstNameMod(name):
    for n in name:
        if n[0] == None:
            name = 'NOT FOUND'
        elif ',' in n[0]:
            name = name[1]
        elif ',' in n[0] and n[1] == None:
            name = name[0]
        elif n[0] != False:
            name = name[0]
        
df.apply(firstNameMod(df['Name']))
```

This did not work because the column I'm selected is being read as a NoneType.

What I have:

```
    Name
0   Robert Marin
1   Katherine Ortiz
2   Sloth, Herbert
3   Perez,
```

What I want:

```
    Name
0   Robert
1   Katherine
2   Herbert
3   NaN
```

sample dataframe:

```
names = {'Name': ['Robert Marin','Katherine Ortiz', 'Sloth, Herbert','Perez,']}
df = pd.DataFrame(names)
```

Comment: `firstNameNMod()` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex to extract your first name:

```
df['Name'].str.extract('(^\w+(?=[^,]*$)|(?<=, )\w+)')[0]
```

output:

```
0       Robert
1    Katherine
2      Herbert
3          NaN
```